# Bulkification issue-System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

Below is my trigger.I am getting bulkification issues.If the number of records of object Sales_Quota__c is huge then on dummy update of invoice records i am getting error in trigger saying "InvoiceTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded".

```
trigger InvoiceTrigger on Invoice_CU__c (before insert, before update,after delete, after insert, after update,after undelete) {
    Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Invoice_CU__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Standard').getRecordTypeId();
    if(recordTypeId != null){
        if(Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isInsert){
            List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotas = [SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c];
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
                for(Sales_Quota__c sq:salesQuotas){
                    if((inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c)  && (inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c)){
                        inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = sq.id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }if (Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isUpdate){
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
                inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = null;
            }
            List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotas = [SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c];
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
                for(Sales_Quota__c sq:salesQuotas){
                    if((inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c)  && (inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c)){
                        inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = sq.id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(Trigger.isafter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUnDelete)){
            Set<id> salesQIds = new Set<id>();
            List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotaList = new list<Sales_Quota__c>();
            if(Trigger.new!=null){
                for(Invoice_CU__c invs : Trigger.new){
                    salesQIds.add(invs.InvoiceToSalesquota__c);
                }    
            }

            if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {
                for(Invoice_CU__c invs : Trigger.old){
                    salesQIds.add(invs.InvoiceToSalesquota__c);
                }
            }
            Decimal Sum;
            for(Sales_Quota__c objSalesQuota : [select Id,Actuals__c,(select Id,Total_Invoice_Price_In_Euro__c from Invoices__r) from Sales_Quota__c where Id IN: salesQIds]){
                Sum=0;
                for (Invoice_CU__c objInv:objSalesQuota.Invoices__r){
                    Sum+= objInv.Total_Invoice_Price_In_Euro__c;
                }
                objSalesQuota.Actuals__c = Sum;
                salesQuotaList.add(objSalesQuota);
            }
            try{
                update salesQuotaList;
            }Catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much sales quotas do you have in org? I think that place when you query all of those may be improved to query only required ones

Comment: 24k records currently i have but it might exceed.So how to improve it.

Comment: I think, trigger handlers should be used. COde would be more reliable and fixable

Comment: well, you can try to  create set with Invoice_Text_Formula__c fields in it, and query only Sales quotes where SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c is in that set

Comment: At which line ? can you provide dummy code.

Comment: Try using the Batch class, so that the execution time will increase and I see Sum+= objInv.Total_Invoice_Price_In_Euro__c; instead of using iteration try using the Aggregate Query, so you can get result in one line. for reference check this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below code for your first part of Trigger:**

```
if(Trigger.isbefore && (Trigger.isInsert|| Trigger.isUpdate)){
         List<String> setOfInvoiceTextDate= new List<String>();
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){ 
             if(inv.Invoice_Text_Date_Formula__c!=NULL)setOfInvoiceTextDate.add(inv.Invoice_Text_Date_Formula__c);
            } 
            Map<String,id> mapOfSqTextAndId= new map<String,id>();
            for(Sales_Quota__c sqid:[Select id,SalesQuota_Text_date_Formula__c FROM Sales_Quota__c where SalesQuota_Text_date_Formula__c IN:setOfInvoiceTextDate]){
               mapOfSqTextAndId.put(sqid.SalesQuota_Text_date_Formula__c.toLowerCase(),sqid.id);    
            }
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
                if(mapOfSqTextAndId.containsKey(inv.Invoice_Text_Date_Formula__c.toLowerCase())){
                inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = null;
                inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c =mapOfSqTextAndId.get(inv.Invoice_Text_Date_Formula__c.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

SO I spend bit time and refactor your code bit check all comments. Since the code written by you. You can understand it better

Trigger code

```
trigger InvoiceTrigger on Invoice_CU__c (before insert, before update,after delete, after insert, after update,after undelete) 
{
    InvoiceTriggerHandler handler = new InvoiceTriggerHandler();
    if(Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        handler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
    if(Trigger.isbefore && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        handler.onBeforeUpdate(Trigger.New);
    }

    if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isInsert )
    {
        handler.onAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
    if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        handler.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.old);
    }
    if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        handler.onAfterDelete(Trigger.Old);
    }
    if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isUnDelete)
    {
        handler.onAfterUnDelete(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

### Trigger Handler

```
public with sharing class InvoiceTriggerHandler
{
    /*before insert */
    public void onBeforeInsert(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        updateInvoiceToSalesquota(lstInvoice_CU);
    }
    /*before update  */
    public void onBeforeUpdate(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        for(Invoice_CU__c inv:lstInvoice_CU)
        {
            inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = null;
        }
        updateInvoiceToSalesquota(lstInvoice_CU);
    }

    /*after insert  */
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        updatesalesQuota(lstInvoice_CU, new List<Invoice_CU__c>());
    }
    /*after update  */
    public void onAfterUpdate(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CUNew, List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CUOld)
    {
        updatesalesQuota(lstInvoice_CUNew, lstInvoice_CUOld);
    }
    /*after Delete  */
    public void onAfterDelete(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        updatesalesQuota(lstInvoice_CU, new List<Invoice_CU__c>());
    }
    /*after unDelete  */
    public void onAfterUnDelete(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        updatesalesQuota(lstInvoice_CU, new List<Invoice_CU__c>());
    }

    //common method for update sales quote
    public void updatesalesQuota(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CUNew, List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CUOld)
    {
        Set<id> salesQIds = new Set<id>();

        for(Invoice_CU__c invs : lstInvoice_CUNew)
        {
            salesQIds.add(invs.InvoiceToSalesquota__c);
        } 
        for(Invoice_CU__c invs : lstInvoice_CUOld)
        {
            salesQIds.add(invs.InvoiceToSalesquota__c);
        }       
        Decimal Sum;
        for(Sales_Quota__c objSalesQuota : [select Id, Actuals__c,
                                                   (select Id, Total_Invoice_Price_In_Euro__c 
                                                      from Invoices__r) 
                                              from Sales_Quota__c 
                                             where Id IN: salesQIds])
        {
            Sum=0;
            for (Invoice_CU__c objInv:objSalesQuota.Invoices__r)
            {
                Sum+= objInv.Total_Invoice_Price_In_Euro__c;
            }
            objSalesQuota.Actuals__c = Sum;
            salesQuotaList.add(objSalesQuota);
        }
        try{
            update salesQuotaList;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /*comman method for before insert and before update */
    public void updateInvoiceToSalesquota(List<Invoice_CU__c> lstInvoice_CU)
    {
        set<String> setInvoice_Text_Formula = new set<String>();
        set<String> setInvoice_Date_Formula = new set<String>();

        //first store all the text formula and date formula in set for query 
        for(Invoice_CU__c inv:lstInvoice_CU)
        {
            if(!String.isEmpty(inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c))
                setInvoice_Text_Formula.add(inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c);
            if(inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c != null)
                setInvoice_Date_Formula.add(Invoice_Date_Formula__c);
        }
        //map to store the both formula text unique values to sales_quote records
        map<String, Sales_Quota__c> mapUniqueToSales_Quota = new map<String, Sales_Quota__c>();
        //query sales quote records based on above sets ad store into map 
        for(Sales_Quota__c sq:[SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c 
                                WHERE SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c IN: setInvoice_Text_Formula 
                                  AND SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c IN: setInvoice_Date_Formula])
        {
            mapUniqueToSales_Quota.put(sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c+sq.SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c, sq);
        }
        //iterate over the lstInvoice_CU and check if both formula combination exist in map or not 
        //if exist then assign the Sales_Quota__c id to InvoiceToSalesquota__c field
        for(Invoice_CU__c inv:lstInvoice_CU)
        {
            if(mapUniqueToSales_Quota.containsKey(inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c+inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c))
            {
                inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = mapUniqueToSales_Quota.get(inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c+inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c).id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two sets- one to contain InvoiceTextFormula values of all trigger.new's INV and other set will contain invoiceDateFormula values of all trigger.new's INV.Suppose InvoiceTextFormula set name is TextSet and invoiceDateFormula  set name is DateSet.

Now, replace `List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotas = [SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c]` with

```
List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotas = [SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c where SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c in:TextSet And SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c in:DateSet
```

Let me know if it helps you